# How do I look get an associated value in a json variable using python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

How do I look up the 'id' associated with the a person's 'name' when the 2 are in a dictionary?

```
user = 'PersonA'
id = ? #How do I retrieve the 'id' from the user_stream json variable?
```

## json, stored in a variable named "user_stream"

```
[
  {
    'name': 'PersonA',
    'id': '135963'
  },
  {
    'name': 'PersonB',
    'id': '152265'
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to decode the JSON structure and loop through all the dictionaries until you find a match:

```
for person in json.loads(user_stream):
    if person['name'] == user:
        id = person['id']
        break
else:
    # The else branch is only ever reached if no match was found
    raise ValueError('No such person')
```

If you need to make multiple lookups, you probably want to transform this structure to a `dict` to ease lookups:

```
name_to_id = {p['name']: p['id'] for p in json.loads(user_stream)}
```

then look up the `id` directly:

```
id = name_to_id.get(name)  # if name is not found, id will be None
```

The above example assumes that names are unique, if they are not, use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_to_id = defaultdict(list)
for person in json.loads(user_stream):
    name_to_id[person['name']).append(person['id'])

# lookup
ids = name_to_id.get(name, [])  # list of ids, defaults to empty
```

This is as always a trade-off, you trade memory for speed.

Comment: There's no way to do it without looping?  I can't "search" for PersonA?

Comment: @sharataka: Not in a manner that'll work with all JSON formatting variations, no.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by all JSON formatting variations though?

Comment: Shouldn't the `else` block be indented on the same level as the `if` block?

Comment: @DavidPärsson: No, it goes with the `for` loop. It is executed if we didn't break out of the loop.

Comment: @sharataka: You are processing JSON objects, and there is no order given for those, So the `id` can come before or after the name. Whitespace is optional, so the id and name could be on the same line, or there could be numerous tabs and newlines in between. Etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh, nice. When reading the code it makes sense, but I didn't know that was a valid flow.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn Pieters's solution is correct, but if you intend to make many such look-ups it's better to load the json and iterate over it just once, and not for every look-up.

```
name_id = {}

for person in json.loads(user_stream):
    name = person['name']
    id = person['id']
    name_id[name] = id

user = 'PersonA'
print name_id[user]
```

Comment: +1. If your data doesn't come with a structure that suits your intended use, then a good practice is to restructure the data first, and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
persons = json.loads(...)
results = filter(lambda p:p['name'] == 'avi',persons)
if results:
    id = results[0]["id"]
```

`results` can be more than 1 of course..